# Program to calculate interest

Tags: java

This program counts first 6 months interest for given amount, it doesn't work where is the mistake?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BalAfter6Months{

  public static void main(String []args){

    int counter=1;
    double interest,SavBal,total,amount;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the monthly saving amount: ");
    amount = sc.nextDouble();

    SavBal = amount;

    while (counter<7) {
      interest = amount * 0.00417;

      total = interest + SavBal;

      amount = amount + SavBal;

      counter++;
   }

      System.out.print(total);

  }

}
```

Comment: You should tell us what you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. Questions of the form  "here's my code, it doesn't work, please tell me what's wrong" are generally considered off-topic here. You must explain what isn't working (show expected and actual output) and explain what debugging you've already done.

Comment: Well if you mean that it does not compile, try initializing `total`

Comment: the compiler says the total might not have been initialized .. i need to print the total amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This avoids unnecessary variables, and IMO is much simpler.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BalAfter6Months{

    public static void main(String []args){

        double interest, balance;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the monthly saving amount: ");

        balance = sc.nextDouble();

        int count = 1
        while (counter < 7) {
            interest = balance * 0.00417;
            balance += interest
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.print(total);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have coded it correctly. You just have to initialize the `total` variable to avoid the compiler error.

```
/* Initialize Total Variable */
double interest,SavBal,total = 0,amount;
```

Input:

```
100
```

Output:

```
102.502
```